# ask android permission on android 4?

Tags: android

I have an app that I published, and it has something like this:

```
requestStoragePermission();
```

and the function:

```
private void requestStoragePermission(){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
@Override //user response
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE){
        //If permission is granted
        if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //Displaying a toast
            String string = getString(R.string.permissionOk);
            Toast.makeText(this,string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            String string = getString(R.string.permissionError);
            Toast.makeText(this,string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

It works ok on android 6... but how will it be interpretation on android 4, for example, which does not need permissions? is it a bad practise?

Comment: `ActivityCompat` is designed for this scenario. You should be fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh! thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

On API levels where it is not required for the user to grant a dangerous permission, requesting that permission does not pop up a dialog for the user and the permission is automatically granted. This still adheres with Google's security policy because for those API levels the user has to grant the permissions during the installation process instead.

Some will tell you to check the API level in your code and only request the permission if it is below 23. This is just an extra layer on top of what the code already does internally and thus increases the complexity of your code. You don't have to do that.

Comment: To expand with a minor point, earlier Api levels ask for permission when installing the app not during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to request persmission in android 4.

You simply have to add the permissions in android-manifest file and everything will be taken care of.

However, make sure your request permission code is not executed in these versions. For that use something like:

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<23){
 //DoNOtRequestPersmissions
        }
```

Comment: *There is no way to request persmission in android 4.* I disagree, you can run the requesting permission code on android 4, the difference is it will automatically grant the permission without user interaction

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks for the add. I did not know that. :)

Comment: It doesn't grant the permisson but it does call the `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` with a list of the current status of those permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, to request permissions, I usually have a function that I call `arePermissionsGranted()`. In that function, if the API level is lower than 23, it automatically says 'the permissions are granted', since you do not need to request them. If API level is 23 or higher, it checks if the permissions have been granted and if not, requests them.